# IIS7 Url Rewrite not being used

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm rebuilding part of an existing asp application, the new parts are build with MVC.

One of the old screens which I'm not touching at the moment needs to point to a new location. For that reason I've set up a URL redirect in IIS on machine level with the following regular expression:

```
^workflows/screen\.asp\?objectid=([0-9]+)(.*)
```

When using the tester I can see that it's a correct expression which catches the necessary items and I need to send the users to the following new URL:

```
http://domainname/newapppart/select/{R:1}
```

When testing it in my browser though it seems as if the rewrite rule is not even in place as I'm still send to the old page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query string is not included in main match string, you have to use `Conditions` to evaluate it.

```
<rule name="MyRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^workflows/screen\.asp$" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="objectid=([0-9]+).*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://domainname/newapppart/select/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```